# Swiper slider is stucks/bounce when using click and drag event at same slider

Tags: jquery, slider, swiper.js

Here is the code which I am writing right now.When I am trying to drag the images in the slider it invokes the hyperlinks and navigates on the image link. Ideally when I am dragging it should drag the content in the slider and when i will click on the images It should navigate to the image link.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {

iOSEdgeSwipeDetection:true,
iOSEdgeSwipeThreshold:0,
    lazyLoading: true,
       mode:'horizontal',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    slidesPerView: 7,
    slidesPerGroup:3,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    simulateTouch:true,
    freeMode: true,
    resizeReInit:true,
   preventClicks: false
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested , but can you try this code

```
var settings = {
               iOSEdgeSwipeDetection:true,
iOSEdgeSwipeThreshold:0,
    lazyLoading: true,
       mode:'horizontal',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    slidesPerView: 7,
    slidesPerGroup:3,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    simulateTouch:true,
    freeMode: true,
    resizeReInit:true,
   preventClicks: false,
              onSlideChangeEnd:function(swiper){

              } ,
                 onTouchEnd:function(swiper,event){
              },
    onInit:function(swiper){

    },
     onClick:function(swiper, event){
         event.preventDefault();
    },
     onTap:function(swiper, event){

    }
               };
```